# performFetch is slow with ios8

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using core data for a project the following code with iOS 7 is faster than 8

```
var fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Test")
let positionDescriptor  = NSSortDescriptor(key: "position", ascending: true)
let remoteIDDescriptor  = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemID", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [positionDescriptor, remoteIDDescriptor]

fetchRequest.predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "item = %@", self.item!)
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
self.frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

self.frc?.performFetch(nil)
self.frc?.delegate = self
```

for example if i fetch 20 items freezes the UI for 2 - 3 seconds

Any ideas thanks!

Comment: Code looks OK. The delay comes from something else. Core Data is certainly faster in iOS8. Make sure the sort fields are indexed, but this should be an unnoticeable difference with <10.000 items.

Comment: well with self sizing cells is iOS 8 the performance is good

Comment: Profile it with Instruments. That will tell you where the problem is.